# Python pandas dataframes: filtering around key dates

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a pandas date-frame `df` with the index being a daily `DatetimeIndex`, and an attached column with `historical_sales`.

If we wanted to filter days in the past where historical_sales were greater than a large number, say `200`, easy enough:

```
df.loc[df['historical_sales'>200]]
```

I'm wondering however, what if we wanted to explore sales patterns on 5 days preceding AND following days when sales were > 200?

Many thanks.

Comment: If want to filter for days around a list_of_dates: [ date1, date2, ...dateN), make sure to convert the list_of_dates = pd.to_datetime(list_of_dates) for the temp_index below to work.  Else you get KeyError: '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think youn need get all index values by list comprehension and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Also is necessary use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for join all indexes together with [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) for remove duplicates.

```
np.random.seed(100)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'historical_sales': np.random.choice([100,200,300], size=20)}, index=rng)
print (df)
            historical_sales
2017-04-03               100
2017-04-04               100
2017-04-05               100
2017-04-06               300
2017-04-07               300
2017-04-08               100
2017-04-09               300
2017-04-10               200
2017-04-11               300
2017-04-12               300
2017-04-13               300
2017-04-14               300
2017-04-15               200
2017-04-16               100
2017-04-17               100
2017-04-18               100
2017-04-19               100
2017-04-20               300
2017-04-21               100
2017-04-22               200
```

---

```
idxmask = df.index[df['historical_sales']>200]
print (idxmask)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-06', '2017-04-07', '2017-04-09', '2017-04-11',
               '2017-04-12', '2017-04-13', '2017-04-14', '2017-04-20'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

#in real data change 1 to 5 for 5 days
temp_index = [df.loc[timestamp - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') : 
                     timestamp + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')].index for timestamp in idxmask]
idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(temp_index))

df1 = df.loc[idx]
print (df1)
            historical_sales
2017-04-05               100
2017-04-06               300
2017-04-07               300
2017-04-08               100
2017-04-09               300
2017-04-10               200
2017-04-11               300
2017-04-12               300
2017-04-13               300
2017-04-14               300
2017-04-15               200
2017-04-19               100
2017-04-20               300
2017-04-21               100
```

Comment: Worked like a wonder, many thanks! Only thing there was a typo i think: mask should be idxmask.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do range slicing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Should look like this (code is pseudocode):

```
great_sales_df = df.loc[df['historical_sales'>200]]
for sale in great_sales_df:
   sales_date = great_sales_df["date"]
   sales_before = sales_date + pd.DateOffset(-5)
   sales_after =  sales_date + pd.DateOffset(+5)
   pattern_df = df.iloc[sales_before:sales_after]
```

This code will not work, but I think the direction is right.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity, I am adding a `new` column which is set to 1 for the row of interest. And for the easy verification the number of window dates have been kept to 1 instead of 5, in the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(51),index=pd.date_range('2015-04-20','2015-06-09'),columns=['A'])
idx = df[df.A >0.5].index

df["new"] = 0

for date in idx:
    current_date = date.to_pydatetime()
    start = current_date - timedelta(days=1)
    end = current_date + timedelta(days=1)

    df.loc[start:current_date]["new"] = 1
    df.loc[current_date:end]["new"] = 1


print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to work with rows before and after, I simply perform a shift.

```
df['preceeding_5th_day'] = df['historical_sales'].shift(5)
df['following_5th_day'] = df['historical_sales'].shift(-5)
```

Then, you can simply make your check and do

```
df.loc[df['historical_sales'>200]]
```

The selected rows then will also have columns about preceeding and following 5th day. Pretty straightforward this way.